# PhpStorm showing space instead of &nbsp;

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2016.2 with a project that uses blade templates. In my Blade templates I use the html encoded character `&nbsp;`. PhpStorm shows `&nbsp;` as a space in the editor, I would like it to show `&nbsp;` unchanged.

What setting do I need to change?

Comment: How does it look exactly? Will you see some hint/popup box when hovering over it with such entity expanded? Will such characters/places have slightly different background? Show some screenshots please.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Temporarily off

This is only cosmetical.

Hover mouse over it to see the code preview. Click it to expand.

[image: nbsp preview]

---

## Permanently off

If you want to turn such code folding off altogether, go to:

**Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding** and uncheck **XML entities**

[image: nbsp off]

From [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205413550-Stop-collapsing-code-folding-of-nbsp-)

Comment: This is a bad answer.

The problem is not cosmetically.

When you're responsible for outputting &nbsp; and not a space ' ', you will want to make sure the &nbsp; is in the html code, and be sure that a stupid IDE did not somehow feel obliged to convert your character to a space.

Skimming a lot of code files should not require mouse interaction. And if you want to configure PhpStorm to not hide the &nbsp;, this should be possible without asking here :)

Comment: @andkrup Code folding is not conversion. The `&nbsp;` character entities are in the HTML code, PhpStorm doesn't change them; it only displays a placeholder for them (that can be easily replaced with the actual content) in order to put them out of the way. The HTML code is easier to read this way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just can't fathom what kind of programmer thinks it's good to hide the code from the coder. It's mind-blowing. This really should not be a default-on setting.  And while we're there: why is this an XML labeled setting affecting code in non-xml files/environments.

Comment: @axiac *The HTML code is easier to read this way* - no it isn't. Or maybe it is for you but not for others, including me. When I type something in my IDE, I want it to show what I typed and nothing else.